# Перебрать все элементы на странице с определённым идентификатором

Tags: jquery

Есть функция, которая перебирает все элементы на странице с определённым классом и поочерёдно сбрасывает с них стили:

```
$('.card').each(function(i){
    setTimeout(() => $(this).css({'opacity': '', 'transform':''}), i*100);
});
```

Но как можно сделать так, чтобы перебирались только те блоки, у которых, например, атрибут `id` больше 6 и меньше 10 и анимировались только они?

```js
$('.card').each(function(i){
if($(this).attr('id') >= 15 && $(this).attr('id') <= 20)
 setTimeout(() => $(this).css({'opacity': '', 'transform':''}), i*100);
});
```

```css
.card {
   transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card" id="1" style="opacity: 0; transform: translateY(40px);">1</div>
<div class="card" id="2" style="opacity: 0; transform: translateY(40px);">2</div>
<div class="card" id="3" style="opacity: 0; transform: translateY(40px);">3</div>
<div class="card" id="4" style="opacity: 0; transform: translateY(40px);">4</div>
<div class="card" id="5" style="opacity: 0; transform: translateY(40px);">5</div>
<div class="card" id="6" style="opacity: 0; transform: translateY(40px);">6</div>
<div class="card" id="7" style="opacity: 0; transform: translateY(40px);">7</div>
<div class="card" id="8" style="opacity: 0; transform: translateY(40px);">8</div>
<div class="card" id="9" style="opacity: 0; transform: translateY(40px);">9</div>
<div class="card" id="10" style="opacity: 0; transform: translateY(40px);">10</div>
<div class="card" id="11" style="opacity: 0; transform: translateY(40px);">11</div>
<div class="card" id="12" style="opacity: 0; transform: translateY(40px);">12</div>
<div class="card" id="13" style="opacity: 0; transform: translateY(40px);">13</div>
<div class="card" id="14" style="opacity: 0; transform: translateY(40px);">14</div>
<div class="card" id="15" style="opacity: 0; transform: translateY(40px);">15</div>
<div class="card" id="16" style="opacity: 0; transform: translateY(40px);">16</div>
<div class="card" id="17" style="opacity: 0; transform: translateY(40px);">17</div>
<div class="card" id="18" style="opacity: 0; transform: translateY(40px);">18</div>
<div class="card" id="19" style="opacity: 0; transform: translateY(40px);">19</div>
<div class="card" id="20" style="opacity: 0; transform: translateY(40px);">20</div>
```

Comment: Зачем вы так делаете? Использование `id` в вашем случае абсолютно неоправдано

Comment: @tutankhamun У меня функция выводит на экран 9 элементов из массива. Потом, по кнопке выводит на экран ещё 9 элементов. Мне каждые новые 9 элементов, выведенных на экран нужно анимировать. Перебор идёт по всем элементам, а не только по свеже-выведенным. В итоге, если вывести 81 элемент на экран, то до 72-81 элемента этот перебор дойдёт нескоро. Соответственно, и анимировать его сможет не сразу. В этом и проблема. Поэтому, было решено использовать уникальные идентификаторы, по которым и определять свеже-выведенные элементы.

Comment: То есть вам нужно анимировать последние 9 элементов?

Comment: @tutankhamun да. В специфика setTimeout у меня состоит в том, что анимирование поочерёдно и анимирует с задержкой по итерации.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Когда вставляете новые строки, назначайте им специальный класс, который означает что элемент требуется анимировать, потом по таймауту убираете этот класс - включается анимация. Таким образом анимироваться будут только последние добавленные элементы.

PS. Старайтесь избегать использования `id` для адресации элементов для JS а также использования встроенных стилей.

```js
function anim() {
  $('.card.anim').each(function(i) {
    setTimeout(() => $(this).removeClass('anim'), i * 100 + 100);
  });
}

$('.append').on('click', function(e) {
  var ix;
  e.preventDefault();
  for (ix = 5; ix >= 0; ix -= 1) {
    $('.container').append($('<div class="card anim">**</div>'));
  }
  anim();
});

anim();
```

```css
.card {
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.anim {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(40px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="append">Еще<button>
<div class="container">
  <div class="card">1</div>
  <div class="card">2</div>
  <div class="card">3</div>
  <div class="card">4</div>
  <div class="card">5</div>
  <div class="card anim">6</div>
  <div class="card anim">7</div>
  <div class="card anim">8</div>
  <div class="card anim">9</div>
  <div class="card anim">10</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает.

Answer (score 0):

```
each(function(i,j) // добавьте второй аргумент в цикл


if (parseInt($(j).attr('id')) <= 10 && parseInt($(j).attr('id')) >= 6) {// проверка ID
        // Ваше преобразование              
    }
```

Comment: прошу прощения за правки

Comment: `css('id')`? Как это связано с проверкой? Второй аргумент равен `this` его нет смысла добавлять

Comment: "атрибут  id больше 6 и меньше 10" , ну проверка на значение id , как вы писали , или я не правильно понял ?

Comment: @MoJlo4HuK `.css()` здесь вообще ни при чём. Это делается при помощи `.attr()`

Comment: упс , делал на сравнение стиля , извиняюсь

Comment: @MoJlo4HuK это не решение. Перебор всё равно происходит по `i`. Первые 5 элементов хоть и не выводится на экран, но цикл через них проходит и делает задержку.

Comment: тогда я не понял задачу

Comment: @MoJlo4HuK обновил код в песочнице. Просмотрите, что произойдёт с элементами. Очередь до 15 элемента дойдёт не сразу.